# turning data connection back on

Tags: android, alarmmanager

The following code successfully turns the data connection off. I want the alarm to fire again to turn it back on.

```
public void triggerEnable(boolean enableData, int hourInDay, int minInDay) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourInDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minInDay);

    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(
            "com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", enableData);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

}
```

Here I make call to the above function

```
            triggerEnable(false, SetTimeActivity.intFromTimeH,
                SetTimeActivity.intFromTimeM);
             //         triggerEnable(true, SetTimeActivity.intToTimeH,
            //                  SetTimeActivity.intToTimeM);
    }
```

I tried with the commented lines but it isnt working. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

```
 public class ConnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String CONN_ACTION = "com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE";
Network objNetwork = new Network();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(CONN_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        boolean enableConn = intent.getBooleanExtra("FLAG_KEY", false);
        objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(context, enableConn);  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I don't see any difference in the statements within the `if` and the `else`. So irrespective of the value of `enableData`, the same code gets executed.

Comment: The first (two) statement passes a boolean false which disconnects the data connection. The next (two) (commented) passes boolean true which is supposed to turn the connection back on but its not working.

Comment: I was referring to the `if`...`else` in your `triggerEnable` method. Probably the check is not necessary.

Comment: I know. Doesn't make any difference though.

Comment: You could try logging the `enableConn` value in the `onReceive` method.